# What happens when rename a file being written in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Suppose a process A has opened a file F and writing to it in HDFS. Now another process B comes and tries to rename file F. Can the rename be successful? If successful, will process A be notified any errors when continuing to write to the file?

Comment: Try and see for yourself? Should be straightforward to test